# MyBatis-Spring java config don't find xml mapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-mybatis

I was trying out Spring java based config. And stuck while trying to use xml mappers(java mappers works fine). Error I'm getting:

```
JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): lt.dm.mappers.StatisticMapper.getFromTo
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:230) [mybatis-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:48) [mybatis-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:65) [mybatis-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:58) [mybatis-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.getFromTo(Unknown Source)
        at lt.dm.controler.JarStatsController.getYear(JarStatsController.java:36) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
```

My config

```
package lt.dm.config;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

@Configuration
@MapperScan("lt.dm.mappers")
public class MyDbConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/dts");
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

my controller (I know I shouldn't use mappers in controllers)

```
package lt.dm.controler;

import lt.dm.mappers.StatisticMapper;
import lt.dm.model.BriefModel;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/JarStats")
public class JarStatsController {

    @Autowired
    StatisticMapper statisticMapper;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<BriefModel>> getAll(
            @RequestParam(value="yearFrom", defaultValue="2005") int yearFrom,
            @RequestParam(value="yearTo", defaultValue="2006") int yearTo){
        List<BriefModel> model = statisticMapper.getall(yearFrom, yearTo);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/2005")
    public String getYear(){
        Integer hi = statisticMapper.getFromTo();
        return hi.toString();
    }
}
```

my java mapper:

```
package lt.dm.mappers;

import lt.dm.model.BriefModel;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;
import java.util.List;

public interface StatisticMapper {

    @Select("select * from STAT.BENDRA where METAI >= #{yearFrom} and METAI <= #{yearTo} order by metai, ketvirtis")
    @Results(
            {@Result(property = "year", column = "METAI"),
            @Result(property = "quarter", column = "KETVIRTIS"),
            @Result(property = "regIn", column = "IREG"),
            @Result(property = "regOut", column = "ISREG"),
            @Result(property = "stillReg", column = "NEISREG"),
            @Result(property = "kapitalLt", column = "KAPITAL"),
            @Result(property = "kapitalEu", column = "KAPITAL_EUR")})
    List<BriefModel> getall(@Param("yearFrom") int yearFrom, @Param("yearTo") int yearTo);

    Integer getFromTo();


}
```

my xml mapper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="lt.dm.mappers.StatisticMapper">

    <select id="getFromTo" resultType="java.lang.Integer" >
        select METAI
        from STAT.BENDRA
        where METAI = 2005
          and ketvirtis = 1
    </select>

</mapper>
```

Comment: Your method getFromTo() is not publicly visible. Is this an issue for XML mappers?

Comment: Only for xml mappers. Select in java file works fine.